# No results come up in my HTML page from PHP query

Tags: php, html, sql

I'm trying to display data from my SQL database on a HTML page through a php query.

I've done a similar query before in the same way and that worked, however this php query doesn't display any results on my html page and I have no idea why.

```
<?php 
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","password","registration"); 
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) 
{ 
    die("Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error()); 
}

$query = "SELECT * FROM goal WHERE id = $_SESSION[userid]";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $query);

if($result == false) {
die("Query failed: ".mysqli_error($con).PHP_EOL.$query);
}

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))  
{ 
    echo "Weight Lost:"."<p>".$row['weightlost']."</p>\n";
    echo "Weight Unit:"."<p>".$row['weightunit']."</p>\n";
    echo "Date set for goal to be reached:"."<p>".$row['whenby']."</p>\n";

} 
mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

Comment: no error checking at all; and you most likely have some.

Comment: I've checked my error logs and there are no errors

Comment: *"however this php query doesn't display any results on my html page"* - as in what, `.html` file? The session array has value or not? the session value is what, integer/string? session started or not?

Comment: Yes, it doesn't display anything in my html file. The session array has value and the value is an integer

Comment: again; is the file extension `.html` or `.php`? when you view your html source, what do you see, "code"?

Comment: .html
I've allowed my html files to read php code.

Comment: I see no code when i view it

Comment: ok and how are you accessing it in your browser, as `http://localhost` or as `file:///`?

Comment: As `http://localhost`

Comment: I've found that when I remove the `id = $_SESSION[userid]` , results appear, however, not for the specific user who is logged in.